# sonar-swift to analyse xcode project

Tags: ios, swift, sonarqube, code-analysis

Im trying to analyse swift app using SonarQube. followed the instructions from [here](https://github.com/Backelite/sonar-swift)

Im able to run the sonarqube server and running sonar-scanner while running it I'm getting this error

com.sonarsource.A.A.B.A: No license for swift

I'm using this plug in, backelite-sonar-swift-plugin-0.2.4.jar i feel this plug in is free and we can use it. correct me it I'm wrong.

Comment: Got solution in from /extensions/plugins folder removed default swift plugin and added this one backelite-sonar-swift-plugin-0.2.4.jar.

Comment: Hey Sarah, can you please tell me what steps have you followed to scan the project right from start?

Answer (score 1):

What I did was:

1. Download Sonarqube LTS version (https://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/)
2. Download and install dependencies and Sonar-Swift from https://github.com/Backelite/sonar-swift (including sonar-scanner)
3. Download sonar-project.properties (https://gist.github.com/Edudjr/db51907068ea76b116d11d9a9b13f05f#file-sonar-project-properties) and configure it according to your project. Place it in your project root folder.
4. Download run-sonar-swift.sh (https://gist.github.com/Edudjr/79a2379842357c33709aecf040d9ae77#file-run-sonar-swift-sh), place it in somewhere in your mac and add to path (/etc/paths). I did a small change in the script because oclint was not running properly.
5. Start your Sonarqube server (sonar.sh console in sonar folder) and run run-sonar-swift.sh in your project root folder. You should be done.

Comment: I followed all steps shared by you but I am getting below error not getting how to fix it `ERROR - Command 'xcodebuild clean build -project Sample.xcodeproj -scheme SampleTests -destination platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 8,OS=12.0 -destination-timeout 360 COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO' failed with error code: 65`

Comment: The trick is to copy the command which has failed to the command line and check what error it gets. Try `xcodebuild clean build -project Sample.xcodeproj -scheme SampleTests -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 8,OS=12.0' -destination-timeout 360 COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO`

Comment: @Edudjr did u get any proper solution for your questine?

Comment: @Edujr any solution for your issue while I am also getting same error for sonarqube

Answer (score 0):

**Manual Installation**

1. In the page dedicated to the plugin you want to install (ex: for Python : SonarPython), click on the "Download" link of the version compatible with your SonarQube version.
2. Upload the downloaded jar file in your SonarQube Server and put it in the directory : `$SONARQUBE_HOME/extensions/plugins`.
3. If another version of the same plugin is already there, you need to remove it, since only one version of a given plugin may be available in the `extensions/plugins` directory.
4. Once done, you will need to restart your SonarQube Server.

https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+a+Plugin

**Backelite Sonar-Swift last release:**

https://github.com/Backelite/sonar-swift/releases